# wrong text is highlighted in officejs

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am searching a initial caps term in a sentence and try to highlight using select() call but I see a non cap term is getting selected.though I am using matchcase search option. below is the sample paragraph:

"Seller shall convey title to the Real Property to Buyer by grant deed in the form of Exhibit "B" attached hereto ("Deed")."

I have to search "Deed" and selcet the same but instead "deed" is getting selected. below is the sample code :

```
'''
textToHighlight = "Deed";
winstance = 0;
                   var rangeCol = para.search(textToHighlight, { matchCase: true });
                    para.context.load(rangeCol);
                    return para.context.sync().then(function () {    
                            rangeCol.items[winstance].select();
                            para.context.sync().then(function () {
                            })
                       })
'''
```

Comment: Your code snippet is incomplete. Please provide a [mcve] so we don't have to attempt recreating from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with your scripts to search on the paragraph you provided, but it works as expected. I tried both online Word and desktop Word. Both get correct result. 
Can you provide more info about your issue? You use Word Online or desktop version? What's the build number?

Thanks，
Flora

Comment: Thanks Flora, Problem is when we perform the above operation on tracked paragraphs. I am working on word online. i Have updated the above code snippet.
Also, i noticed similar behavior for search option matchWholeWord aswell. I am suspecting tracked objects could be causing this

Comment: I think range objects returned after doing search operation on a tracked paragragh with search option is wrong though it looks to be correct. Could you please try the same on a tracked paragraph.

Comment: I add: "context.trackedObjects.add(para);" to the head of your code snippet and run, but still get 'Deed' selected.

Comment: If possible, maybe you can share a doc to me and I can have a try there. Thanks. You can mail to: kaidal@microsoft.com.

Comment: We can repro the issue now, We will try to fix it. Thanks for reporting the issue.